# I'm having problems resubmitting data from form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following scenario:

- The user fills an HTML form
- The user presses the submit button
- Something unexpectedly bad happens
- The server retrieves an error page with a retry button. This page does not have the original form anymore. When the user clicks the retry button I want the last post data to be resubmitted

I don't even know if it's possible. I'm trying this on the `retry` button: 
`window.location.reload(true);`

The result is:

- On firefox it works perfectly. It reposts the data and shows the resulting HTML to the user.
- On Google Chrome it does not repost the data, it kind of uses a GET on the same URL, I'll take a look at Fiddler to make sure
- IE 9 reposts the data but shows a blank screen in return. If I reload it will show the proper page.

I'd like every of them to work as Firefox. I guess the problem is in the absense of the original form in this error page.

Is there anything I can do in JavaScript to make them all have the proper behavior?

Comment: What method are you using in your form, GET or POST?
if you are using post im afraid that you lost the form data when you change the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include the post data in the retry form. Wrap the post data in a `<form>` and resubmit the form.

Form:

```
<form id="retryform" name="retryform" action="postfile.html" method="post">
    <!-- post data -->
</form>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('retryform').submit();
// or
document.forms["retryform"].submit();
// or
document.retryform.submit();
```

Comment: document.getElementById('myform').submit(); not 'retryform' ;-) and the form needs the name/id 'retryform'